# Chrome Extension: How to use inline installation for multiple verified sites with one Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome Extension, i want to use inline installation to install this extension in my site. I have 2 sites: *x.com and *y.com. I know how to use inline installation and verify sites BUT my problem is I can select only one site as the verified site for a particular extension and only this site selected can using inline installation and other site not implement inline installation. So someone can help me config any thing to use inline installation in both sites? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible at the moment to install from multiple verified domains. There is a feature request you can track [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152427).

Although it doesn't seem to apply to your case, note that if you verify example.com you can install from x.example.com and y.example.com.

Comment: It looks like there is some movement on this feature request! Comment #115 on issue 152427 by jawag@chromium.org: Support multiple verified domains for inline installation
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152427#c115 " Hey Folks, Thanks for your patience. We've set up a form that you can now use to apply to have this functionality enabled for your developer account: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdZXaDON1Kns14H9Qy3hcQtj3EGD2Ay-1fS5uDO03rLDerbHg/viewform?c=0&w=1
 Please fill out the form if you're interested."